# couldn't figure out the string count behaviour in certain input

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
string = input("Enter the string: ")
sub_string = input("Enter sub string: ")
count = 0 
idx = 0
while string.count(sub_string, idx) != 0:
    count += string.count(sub_string, idx)
    idx = string.index(sub_string, idx)
    idx += 1
    if string.count(sub_string, idx) == 0:
        print(count)
        break
```

when i give this code input as follows:

```
ininini
ini
```

It prints output `4`. I tried running debugger and found out that it is incrementing count with `+2` in the first step instead of `+1` and I couldn't figure out that. Any suggestions would be very much helpful.

Comment: Use `count += 1`.

Comment: @Austin Write an answer that explains why he's getting the wrong result and why that's the solution.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
count += 1
```

instead of

```
count += string.count(sub_string, idx)
```

`string.count(sub_string, idx)` is 2 initially, and that's why you end up adding 2 in first iteration (instead of intended 1), thereby getting a 1 more than expected.

What you need is to increment `count` by 1 in every iteration and if you make this change, you get 3 as output.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `for` loop instead:

```
string = input("Enter the string: ")
sub_string = input("Enter sub string: ")
count = 0 

for index in range(len(string) - len(sub_string) + 1):
    if string[index: index + len(sub_string)] == sub_string:
        count += 1

print(count)
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are tyring to reach to get the length of the string, just use

```
len(string)
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The questioner asked for help to understand the behavior of the program.

Comment: you should atleast read the question before answering the question.